# Select rows based on condition and set values from a vector

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, selection

I want to set the entire rows to a value from a vector, if a condition in on column is met.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 1], ['a', 1, 1], ['b', 1, 1]], columns=('one', 'two', 'three'))
vector = pd.Series([2,3,4])
print(df)

  one  two  three
0   a    1      1
1   a    1      1
2   b    1      1
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
df_wanted = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 1], ['a', 1, 1], ['b', 4, 4]], columns=('one', 'two', 'three'))
print(df_wanted)

  one  two  three
0   a    1      1
1   a    1      1
2   b    4      4
```

I tried this but it gives me error:

```
df.loc[df['one']=='b'] = vector[df['one']=='b']
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

// m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify columns in list for set:

```
df.loc[df['one']=='b', ['two', 'three']] = vector[df['one']=='b']
print(df)
  one  two  three
0   a    1      1
1   a    1      1
2   b    4      4
```

Or if need more dynamic solution - select all numeric columns:

```
df.loc[df['one']=='b', df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns] = vector[df['one']=='b']
```

Or compare only once and assign to variable:

```
m = df['one']=='b'
df.loc[m, df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns] = vector[m]
```

Comment: Thanks,
I like the last one. Do you have a more general solution for all columns. I have 250 columns in my real case, all with different dates as column names.

Comment: Actually, it does!